# Why are geolocations on Twitter "rounded"?

Tags: r, geolocation, twitter

I'm plotting some geolocations `(lon, lat)` of tweets collected using the Stream API with a 7mi. radius. The picture below shows two maps of the same data, but using different alpha/transparency for each observation.

Looking at the map on the left, I noticed that the geolocations follow mostly a sort of imaginary "grid" with specific nodes. 
Anyone could help me to understand why this pattern surfaces?

[image]

Of course, I do have roundings in the coordinates, eg:

```
"loc: 42.7388,13.1798"         "loc: 42.6252,13.2948"         "loc: 42.6008,13.293"          "loc: 42.73,13.2028"          
"loc: 42.66918468,13.27893702"
```

but my question is why these roundings occur since I assumed that the Twitter API would guarantee the same level of precision?

Comment: It could either be the precision of the tweeter's GPS or other location data, or the twitter client only sending to a certain precision. Can you see what client sent the tweet? Is the grid 1/10 of a degree? Or is it a precise number of metres? Hmmmm

Comment: I didn't not scrape the data but they were collected using the Twitter API. The thing is _some_ of the points are tracked at a high level of precision, some are rounded to the 4th decimal (hence the "grid" pattern). I was wondering why there is such a volatility in Twitter data though. The accuracy is definetely higher close to cities, and less in rural areas. I wonder if anyone ever had the same issues when dealing with twitter geolocation.

Comment: It doesn't seem like Twitter provides only four decimal points, at least not a while back: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/119923/converting-twitter-tweets-into-points?rq=1

Comment: It seems based on the version of the software that is used, and on the device: https://help.twitter.com/en/safety-and-security/tweet-location-settings

Comment: @underdark I'm not saying it does, otherwise, there wouldn't be any difference between the two maps. But it looks like many records are being rounded. I added a sample of my data to show that I do in fact have records with different degrees of accuracy

Comment: they are being aggregated using a fishnet tessellation, or something similar.

Comment: @atxgis any idea about who does the aggregation? Is the device that cannot communicate with a level of accuracy that is high enough?

Comment: There is an option when tweeting to share precise location which is turned off by default. Can this be the reason for the rounding?

Comment: @Techie_Gus is that the same as for sharing the location? How is "precise" defined?

Comment: @Dambo I didn't get your first question. As for the second I don't have data to compare precise location Vs. not precise.

Comment: this could be linked with some privacy issues. If it is too precise you can find the address of everybody.

Comment: I'm surprised they have that many decimals. I also think privacy. With the data you have, you can generate a pretty nice looking heat map. You could also add a small amount of random jitter to your points before making the heat map. Of course, depends on what your goal is.

Comment: @user1269942 I was interested in understanding tweets' precision, and it turned out that ca. 30% is rounded to 4 decimals

Comment: @user1269942 Given a large enough data set, the average of truly-random random offsets is zero.  In such a scheme you could e.g. find someone's home address by looking for the largest cluster (in terms of point count) and averaging the cluster's point locations.

Comment: @AlexHajnal good point but that is still possible to an extent even with the "rounded" locations, at least in areas that are not densely populated. I wonder if privacy was really a concern, shouldn't we see measures way less precise than 4 decimals?

Comment: @Dambo Valid point.  If you're going to provide location data at all you're going to have trade-offs.  Honestly, even rounding to the hemisphere level could cause privacy problems, e.g. someone from Mumbai claiming to be in London on business but posting from a beach in Hawai'i.

Answer (score 4):

I have looked at tweets to some extent. But not in your area.

But I suspect this is down to two types of tweets.

Actual tweets that fall into two categories. The correct geolocation with specific precision (see the tweets in the urban area), and town level geolocation (see the stacks in the urban area).

Then you have automated tweets. These are the ones that fall on the grids. For example for the data I am capturing:

[image]

The tweet highlighted above the black lines are all from an automated flood alert system.

I would check your data first to see if there are any trends.

Comment: You mean those are tweets from the same system but from different locations? What would the purpose be? I'll take a look and get back to you, I remember thinking about what you mentioned, but I actually have different levels of rounding (not just either 4 or 9 decimals). That suggests rounded geolocations are not necessarily produced from discrete geotags.

Comment: I'm suggesting there is a twitter bot that is tweeting the gridded locations. For example in my tweets its a flood alert bot. These are geolocated flood alerts, but the locations fall along a grid.

Comment: Yes, I got what you mean. I was just wondering whatfor...

Comment: If I was creating a bot I would probably do it to 4 decimal places as well. Otherwise you are suggesting a level of accuracy that just cannot be attained if you are not on the ground. 4 digits is down to around 10 meters, https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8650/measuring-accuracy-of-latitude-and-longitude.

Comment: Again, I get that, but what I am trying to say is: why would you need a bot that mimics different locations for tweeting flooded-related content. What can the goal possibly be?